# Text Changed Event Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox

I got 2 Dropdown list, 1 Radio button and 1 Textbox along with a Button. I am trying to Disable Button when Dropdowns,Radio Buttons are not selected alon with Empty Textbox. I am able to Disable the button for Dropdown and Radio Button and displaying the message as "Invalid Selection" and for this I have written code on Selected Index Change Event and even in Button Click Event and its working fine. But I am not able to Disable the Button when the Textbox is Empty. Want this Button to be Enabled only when I type something in Textbox and when i try to Click the Button When Textbox is Empty i need a message to be displayed saying "Please Enter a Comment". I have tried Text Changed Event for TextBox too but it is not firing. And Please anybody let me know how to put all these together in Button Click event using Flags.

Note: There are 2 Error messages to be displayed upon Button Click. This should come in loop with Flags being assigned.

So far I have tried this,

Button Click Code:

```
protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DrpForYear.SelectedItem.Text == "Please Select" || DrpForMonth.SelectedItem.Text == "Please Select" || RadView.SelectedItem.Text == "")
        {
            LblErr.Text = "Invalid Selection!!!";
            LblErr.Visible = true;
            BtnSave.Enabled = false;
            BtnSave.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        else
            {
                DTO objc = new DTO();

                int Flag = 0;

                LblLogdInUsername.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
                objc.LogdInUsername = LblLogdInUsername.Text;

                objc.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

                objc.Comments = Server.HtmlEncode(this.TxtComments.Text);

                objc.Company = LblCompany.Text;

                LblName.Text = Session["Name"].ToString();
                objc.Name = LblName.Text;

                objc.Year = DrpForYear.SelectedItem.Text;

                objc.Month = DrpForMonth.SelectedItem.Text;

                objc.ViewPreference = RadView.SelectedItem.Text;


                int X = obj.InsertButtonComment(objc);

                if (X >= 0)
                {
                    Flag = 1;
                }

                else
                {
                    Flag = 0;
                }

                if (Flag == 1)
                {
                    LblSuccess.Visible = true;
                    LblSuccess.Text = "Comment Saved";
                    LblErr.Visible = false;
                    BtnSave.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    LblErr.Visible = true;
                    LblErr.Text = "Failed To Save Comment!!!";
                    LblSuccess.Visible = false;
                }

                objc.LogdInUsername = Convert.ToString(Session["LogdInUsername"]);
                DataSet GrdVC = obj.GetButtonComment(objc);
                DataView GrdViewC = new DataView();
                GrdViewC.Table = GrdVC.Tables[0];
                gvData.DataSource = GrdViewC;
                gvData.DataBind();

                TxtComments.Text = "";
                DrpForYear.ClearSelection();
                DrpForMonth.ClearSelection();
                RadView.Text = "";
         }
    }
```

DDL Selected Index Codes:

```
    protected void DrpForYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DrpForYear.SelectedItem.Text == "Please Select")
        {
            LblErr.Text = "Invalid Selection!!!";
            LblErr.Visible = true;
            BtnSave.Enabled = false;
            BtnSave.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        else
        {
            BtnSave.Enabled = true;
            BtnSave.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#666666");
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }

    protected void DrpForMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DrpForMonth.SelectedItem.Text == "Please Select")
        {
            LblErr.Text = "Invalid Selection!!!";
            LblErr.Visible = true;
            BtnSave.Enabled = false;
            BtnSave.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        else
        {
            BtnSave.Enabled = true;
            BtnSave.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#666666");
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

Textbox Changed Event Code:

```
    protected void TxtComments_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TxtComments.Text == "")
        {
            LblErr.Text = "Please Enter a Comment!!!";
            LblErr.Visible = true;
            BtnSave.Enabled = false;
            BtnSave.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        else if (TxtComments.Text != "")
        {
            BtnSave.Enabled = true;
            BtnSave.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#666666");
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtComments" runat="server" BorderColor="#666666" BorderWidth="1px" 
 Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#034599" Height="106px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="617px" ontextchanged="TxtComments_TextChanged">
```

Comment: it would be helpful for people to help you ...if you be precise and show us the exact portion of the code that is the problem..instead pasting your full code and expecting people to read

Comment: could you please post Design code(aspx file)?

Comment: @iJay Thnks for replying. I have pasted only those code which is useful for others to get know what and how I am trying to get. Infact I have mentioned in my Post clearly about the problem.

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi yeah sure will update my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** You need to set `AutoPostBack` property of the `TextBox` to `True` .

**2.** while comparing the input `String` with `EmptyString`, you need to `Trim` the input so that `whitespaces` would be removed.

**or**

you can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` to check for `null`,`empty` and `whitespaces`.
Try This:

**Design Code**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtComments" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TxtComments_TextChanged"   
AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Code Behind:**  using `Trim()` function

```
   protected void TxtComments_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TxtComments.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            LblErr.Text = "Please Enter a Comment!!!";
            LblErr.Visible = true;
            BtnSave.Enabled = false;
            BtnSave.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }    
        else
        {
            BtnSave.Enabled = true;
            BtnSave.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#666666");
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

**or**  using `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` function

```
 protected void TxtComments_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtComments.Text))
        {
            LblErr.Text = "Please Enter a Comment!!!";
            LblErr.Visible = true;
            BtnSave.Enabled = false;
            BtnSave.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }    
        else
        {
            BtnSave.Enabled = true;
            BtnSave.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#666666");
            BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2:** display TextBox error message as first error

```
protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (TxtComments.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        LblErr.Text = "Please Enter a Comment!!!";
        LblErr.Visible = true;
        BtnSave.Enabled = false;
        BtnSave.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }    
   else if (DrpForYear.SelectedItem.Text == "Please Select" || DrpForMonth.SelectedItem.Text == "Please Select" || RadView.SelectedItem.Text == "")
    {
        LblErr.Text = "Invalid Selection!!!";
        LblErr.Visible = true;
        BtnSave.Enabled = false;
        BtnSave.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        BtnSave.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    else
    {
          /*your code*/
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks mate I totally forgot about using AutoPostBack. Will try it and let u know. and Thanks for that "Trim" :)

Comment: Need 1 more help. I am trying to display an Error Message on Buton click when TextBox is Empty. I need the message as "Please Enter a Comment" but right now I am getting as "Invalid Selection" just coz of loop placed in BtnSave with all together. So can u please let me know how to seperately display that

Comment: @Arjun: you need to add empty check in btnSave click event as the first check, see my edited answer with `solution2`

Comment: Thanks a ton. I just reversed ur solution2 I needed Invalid Selection as First Error Message. Evrything is working absolutely fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

`TxtComments.AutoPostBack= true`

in Code behind

Or

`AutoPostBack="True"` in TextBox Design Page

Like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtComments" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

set Autopostback into true

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtComments" runat="server" BorderColor="#666666" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#034599" Height="106px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="617px" ontextchanged="TxtComments_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
```